# How to handle an array in a stored procedure on DB2?

Tags: sql, arrays, stored-procedures, db2

I'm developing an app which store data in DB2, and I should be able to 'delete' data in bulk in a table of a DB. Actually the way to 'delete' the data is by changing its 'deleted' value to 'Y'.

The form of the table is:

id |  name   | deleted |

1  | name1 | N  |

2  | name2 | N  |

...

x  | namex | N  |

What I want to do is to make a SQL stored procedure which take as a parameter one array with the IDs of the items I need to change from 'N' to 'Y'.

The way I do it (individually) is:

```
UPDATE MyTable DELETED = 'Y' where id = '1';
```

So with an stored procedure I should only send the array with this form:

```
[1, 20, 5, ... , x]
```

and the rows with those Id should be changed to Y.

The structure for the stored procedure I was thinking about is:

```
PROCEDURE deleteSeveral (arrayWithIds)

LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN

    -- loop for ids array
            UPDATE MyTable DELETED = 'Y' where id = arrayWithIds[i]; 
    -- Ciclo para recorrer el arreglo

END
```

Could anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What operating-system runs the Db2-server (Z/OS, i-series,Linux/unix/windows) ?  and what version is the Db2?   Also, from which programming-language will you CALL the stored-procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the list of IDs as an "xml-like" string:

```
UPDATE MyTable t
SET DELETED = 'Y'
where exists (
  select 1
  from xmltable (
    '$D/d/i' passing xmlparse(document '<d><i>1</i><i>20</i><i>5</i></d>') as "D" 
    columns
      i int path '.'
  ) p
  where p.i=t.id
)
```